# No route Matching in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am getting the following error with a nested resource route:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/admin/cities/50eb48e38bffa6daca000001/areas/50eb48ec8bffa6daca000002/edit"
```

My code for the edit form renders like this:

```
<%= form_for(@area, url: edit_city_area_path(params[:city_id], @area.id) ) do |f| %>
```

Comment: What's the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: why is your form submiting to the edit url? That's unusual

Comment: argh. thanks @Frederick, silly mistake. THink i should go sleep now :), too many hours coding. Post an answer and i will accept, i had the wrong named url.